# XCode 13 beta unable to load Metal CoreImage Kernel

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, core-image, metalkit

This looks to be a weird XCode 13 beta bug (including beta 5). Metal Core Image kernels fail to load from the library giving error

> 2021-08-26 12:05:23.806226+0400 MetalFilter[23183:1751438] [api] +[CIKernel kernelWithFunctionName:fromMetalLibraryData:options:error:] Cannot initialize kernel with given library data.
>
> [ERROR] Failed to create CIColorKernel: Error Domain=CIKernel Code=6
> "(null)" UserInfo={CINonLocalizedDescriptionKey=Cannot initialize
> kernel with given library data.}

It loads and runs perfectly fine on XCode 12.5. Perhaps some setting is missing in XCode 13 or is it a bug in XCode 13 beta 5?

Here is the sample code with which the bug can be reproduced.

[MetalCoreImageFilter sample code](https://github.com/JoshuaSullivan/MetalKernel)

Below scripts are mentioned in Build rules of target as advised in WWDC2020.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work when you remove the `-I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` part from the second script.

Though it is mentioned in the WWDC video, it actually causes problems when `MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` is empty. See [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650946?answerId=616138022#616138022) in the forum. Usually, you don't need that parameter if you don't have a complicated file graph or external dependencies.